# GCM push notification icon

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In the official documentation of the GCM [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options) they mention how to put an icon for a push notification by this Example

```
{
    "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
  }
```

my question is "myicon" is the name of the icon, where does it exist?
For example: i have in my project in android studio in drawable "myicon.png"?
or where is it?
Please somebody explain and thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah you will have it in your drawable. So according to its name you will make your logic or use to fetch the icon by name.

Comment: @ArjunGurung i didn't understand do you mean i have to write some code also on the Android Side?

Comment: yeah you have @Haidar

Answer (score 0):

Use your app icon from `drawable` like `.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon)` where appicon is a `.png` file from your `drawable` folder

Or use this code:

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icond)
         .setContentTitle("Start Launcher")
         .setContentText(message)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setOngoing(true)
         .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
         .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

   NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTIFICATION , notificationBuilder.build());
```